# Kotlin Mockito veirfy not invoked in a coroutine test

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I got an error while doing a kotlin coroutine test. I'm pretty sure the function is called because I saw the logs. I'm not sure what does the error message mean. Is this related to coroutine (running on different thread) or the context (using a customized context to trigger onStart)?

> Wanted but not invoked: testActivity.fetch();
> -> at com.example.cws.testActivity.fetch(testActivity.kt:322)
>
> However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
> testActivity.getStateListener$TestApp_release();
> -> at com.example.cws.testActivity.getStateListener$TestApp_release(testActivity.kt:113)

Implementation:

```
val stateListener = object : StateEventListener{
   override fun onStart(testContext: TestEventContext) {
      launch {
         fetch()
      }
   }
}

suspend fun fetch() {
    ***
}
```

Test function:

```
@Test
fun should_fetch_when_started()= runBlocking {
    testActivityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestActivity::class.java)
    testActivity = spy(testActivityController
            .create()
            .start()
            .get())
    testActivity.stateListener.onStart()
    verify(testActivity, times(1)).fetch()
}
```

I've tried to temporarily update the suspend function to a normal function, but same error observed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying the latest [coroutine test library](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test)

```
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.1"
```

It lets you wait for the coroutine to finish in the `runTest` scope (instead of `runBlocking`), like this:

```kotlin
@Test
fun should_fetch_when_started() = runTest {
    testActivityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestActivity::class.java)
    testActivity = spy(testActivityController
            .create()
            .start()
            .get())
    testActivity.stateListener.onStart()

    advanceUntilIdle() // wait for the coroutine to complete

    verify(testActivity, times(1)).fetch()
}
```

In your case, it probably ran the coroutine after the `verify` call instead of before.

You may need to define a Coroutine test rule as well to set the main dispatcher to a test dispatcher if you aren't already, like this:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutineTestRule constructor(val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher())
    : TestWatcher() {

    val scope = TestScope(testDispatcher + Job())

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

and use it in your unit test

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {

    @get:Rule
    var coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()

    @Test
    fun testCoroutineCall() = runTest {

        var index = 0
        coroutineTestRule.scope.launch {
            delay(500)
            index = 1
        }

        advanceUntilIdle()

        assertEquals(1, index)
    }
}
```